# How to calculate start radius, end radius and angle for clothoid segments?

Tags: calculus, geometry, curves, plane-curves

I have a following construction:

*Clothoid -- Circle Arc -- Clothoid -- Clothoid*

which should form a smooth G2-continuous curve.

Clothoids are parameterized with *clothoid parameter* $A$ and *length* $L$. For the circle, its *radius* and *arc length* are given.

I should get the clothoids parameterized through start radius, end radius and angle. Can this be done?

I tried with usual formulas that can be found on wikipedia and on this site. For the first clothoid i took a big start radius i.e. $R=\infty$ and went on from there, taking the last end radius as the next starting one and so on. This didn't work as I thought.

Comment: "which should form a (continuous $\to$ derivable)"

Comment: Would you please elaborate? How can I derive those 3 parameteres from the 2 that are given?

Comment: [Here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/292669884_The_Clothoid_Computation_A_Simple_and_Efficient_Numerical_Algorithm)  is a recent reference.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3289195/688039) and [this other too](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3359006/688039) Now notice you need more data than those you told about.

Comment: My first remark was that "continuous" needs to be replaced by "derivable" or more exactly $G_1$ or $G_2$. Gluing two curves even making a right angle will give you continuity ! What you need is a **smooth** gluing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say how exactly it didn't work, but it should have worked.

You are given $Clo_1(A_1,L_1)$, $Arc(R,L)$, $Clo_2(A_2,L_2)$, $Clo_3(A_3,L_3)$.

You want  $Clo_1(R_{11},R_{12},\Delta\Theta_1)$, $Clo_2(R_{21},R_{22},\Delta\Theta_2)$, $Clo_3(R_{31},R_{32},\Delta\Theta_3)$ where $R_{12} = R = R_{21}$, $Clo_1$ goes from $s_{11}$ to $s_{12}$, $L_1 = s_{12} - s_{11}$, $R_{Clo_1}(s_{11}) = R_{11}$, $R_{Clo_1}(s_{12}) = R_{12}$, etc.

Then we must have $\{ R_{11}s_{11} = (A_1)^2 = R_{12}s_{12} = Rs_{12}, L_1 = s_{12} - s_{11} \}$ (and similarly for $\__2$ and $\__3$).

The above system of two equations is trivially solvable, for each of the clothoids, giving us their edge radii $R_{ij}$, the $s_{ij}$ values, and hence their edge $\Theta$s, and hence their $\Delta\Theta$s:

$$ \Theta = s^2/2A^2 $$
$$ \Theta_1 = s_1^2/(2R_1s_1) = s_1/(2R_1)$$
$$\Theta_2 = s_2/(2R_2)$$
$$ \Delta\Theta_1 = \Theta_2 - \Theta_1$$

Your error seems to be that
you started from setting $R_{11}=\infty$. Instead, the arc's radius determines the rest.